# [topic neo4j REST API]Can't Remove All Entries With a given node

Tags: neo4j

I create node

> node[16]{name:"test01",key01:"value01",key02:"value02"}

when i exc

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/node/kvnode/16
```

I still see node information:

> node[16]{name:"test01",key01:"value01",key02:"value02"}

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your REST call isn't right, it only deletes the index, not the node. If you want to delete the node, use this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/node/16
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer，it's my fault,I want remove all entries with a given node from an index,So i will use find node by exact match     to validate result is correct.